# Script to save ouput of SQL query into txt file

Tags: database, shell, unix

I'm runing a sql query with the help of shell script. I want to save the output of query in a text file. Please help me out

Below is the script

```
export SQLPLUS=/opt/cia/oracle-client/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/sqlplus export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/cia/oracle-client/product/11.2.0/client_1
$SQLPLUS -s USERNAME/PASSSWORD@DB_NAME< 
select OBJECT_ID from ACOS where ID='4141'; spool off
EOF'
!echo "Spool file generated..." clear buffer
exit;
```

Now i want the out put of this to be saved in a file Please help

Comment: Is it oracle?, without spooling, are you getting output on terminal?. If yes then redirection operator should be enough else parse the spool file in same shell script to get required output in a file

Answer (score 0):

you can do following;

```
your code...
...
..
$SQLPLUS -s USERNAME/PASSSWORD@DB_NAME <<EOF > output.txt
-sql query-
..
..
exit;
EOF
```

output will be saved in `output.txt`.